# Null pointer exception occurs when calling getText from EditText in OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a custom dialog box. When i click "OK", I would like it to get the text from its EditText field. However, it throws a null pointer exception.

Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_delivered, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.llDeliveredDialog));

builder.setMessage("Dialog message");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etGivenTo);
    String value = text.getText().toString();
    }
});

builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.show();
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llDeliveredDialog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etGivenTo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: put this to in onCreate method : final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etGivenTo); and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 final EditText text = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.etGivenTo);
                                 ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    final EditText text = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.etGivenTo); 
    String value = text.getText().toString();
    }
});
```